# Turtle library and Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, libraries, turtle-graphics

I tried to import turtle library and it is not there. But when I use from the terminal Python, it works.

So I tried to download like a package but I found a different turtle there.

[image]

What should I do to find and import the right turtle? or how did you guys use it in Pycharm?

Comment: turtle is builtin ... if you are using python you can import turtle ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best solution would be to install Anaconda, which is an application that gives you the necessities for Python (which is what I'm doing):
https://www.anaconda.com/